# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)

Tags: r

mycode:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) +
  geom_density_ridges(rel_min_height = 0.005) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  theme_ridges()
```

the error:

```
Picking joint bandwidth of 2.7
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type 
quosure/formula. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  参数值意味着不同的行数: 2, 512
```

Comment: It is not showing any error for me if the data used is the default one

Comment: same error arisen when i run the code "ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + geom_density_ridges()", i don't know how to solve this quesiton.

Comment: may be it has to do with the version of the packages.  Please check the version and update if needed